# Effect of inserting a single sample on the spectrum

Tags: frequency-spectrum

I have read about interpolating 0s uniformly in a time domain sequence and its effect on the resulting spectrum. I am wondering what happens to the spectrum when you insert just one sample (say a 0 or any other value if that makes it easier to deal with), such that the samples after it in the original sequence get shifted to the right in time (but the ones before the inserted sample remain unaffected). Can someone help me with how to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Given the duality property of the Fourier transform, the effect on the waveforms (regardless if your independent variable is time or frequency)! So if you understand well that zero-padding a time domain waveform will interpolate more samples in frequency, then that is exactly what will happen when you go in the other direction: If you zero pad the frequency domain waveform, it will interpolate more time samples in the time domain waveform. In both cases neither approach adds more information but provides the interpolated line in between the existing samples.